# Video card and monitor don't work with each other, fine with other cards/monitors

Tags: graphics-card, display, dvi, amd-radeon

I'm having some problems with my ASUS Radeon HD 5770 video card and Samsung Syncmaster P2370 monitor:

1. I found if I directly connect my monitor to the DVI port on the card, there is no display. I have to use an adapter to connect to the VGA port or HDMI port, then the monitor works.
2. I changed to another video card (GTX 460) and connected to its DVI port from the monitor; it works just fine.
3. I switched back to the HD 5700, and using another ViewSonic monitor, connected it to the card's DVI port and it works fine too.

I don't know what the problem is. It seems the card works fine with other monitors and the monitor works fine as well with other cards.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I connected my 6870 to my brother's Asus monitor and it wouldn't display for the life of me. But I hook it up to my Asus or Princeton monitor and it works fine. Not sure what the problem is/was but since it wasn't my monitor I didn't look into it too much. If you have displayport on the video card you could try getting a DP to DVI cable.

Comment: Did you try a different DVI cable?

Comment: Did you try booting with the monitors plugged in? Sometimes this is a driver issue (in which case your OS is vital information. Other times it can be a graphics card issue, a cable issue (as David says, try a different cable) or a monitor issue.

Comment: Thanks for help! 

I had tried different cables and the same problem.